# Settimeout, bind and this

Tags: javascript, this, settimeout

Here I have copied code snippet from MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

```
function LateBloomer() {
  this.petalCount = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
}

// Declare bloom after a delay of 1 second
LateBloomer.prototype.bloom = function() {
  window.setTimeout(this.declare.bind(this), 1000);
};

LateBloomer.prototype.declare = function() {
  console.log('I am a beautiful flower with ' +
    this.petalCount + ' petals!');
};

var flower = new LateBloomer();
flower.bloom();  
// after 1 second, triggers the 'declare' method
```

The most confusing part is : `window.setTimeout(this.declare.bind(this), 1000);`

I understand how `this` works and `this` inside settimeout is always bound to global object.I know there can be *var self* or *var that* inside bloom function.

There are two `this` in that line but which `this` refers to what and how that works is totally confusing.

How works?

Comment: Both `this`'s are the same object. `Bind` returns the function with the context or `this` explicitly set. so when `setTimeout` eventually runs it can't override `this` to global so it remains set to the `this` of the `bloom` method.

Answer (score 8):

First of all read this [article](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this), which offers a very nice explanation about how `this` works.

`.bind(this, args)` just helps you to pass your `this` context inside your function (because inside it in your example by default `this` is `undefined` or refers to `window`).

Also `bind` is a nice alternative to this:

```
// Declare bloom after a delay of 1 second
LateBloomer.prototype.bloom = function() {
  var self = this;
  window.setTimeout(self.declare, 1000);
};
```

And as the last point in `es6` you can do it in this way:

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
  //do some stuff
}, 1000);
```

instead of

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
  //do some stuff
}.bind(this), 1000);
```

this allow you to not think about `this`.

Answer (score 5):

MSDN defines `Function.prototype.bind()` as,

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

By using `.bind(this)` we are passing `this` to the function `declare`

See this snippet.

```js
function LateBloomer() {
  console.log(this.constructor);
  this.petalCount = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
}

// Declare bloom after a delay of 1 second
LateBloomer.prototype.bloom = function() {
  window.setTimeout(this.declare.bind(this), 1000);
};

LateBloomer.prototype.undefinedbloom = function() {
  window.setTimeout(this.declare, 1000);
};

LateBloomer.prototype.declare = function() {
  console.log(this.constructor);
  console.log('I am a beautiful flower with ' +
this.petalCount + ' petals!');
};

var flower = new LateBloomer();
flower.bloom();
flower.undefinedbloom();
```

In the function `undefinedbloom` we are just calling the declare function. So the object will be the `window` object. It doesn't have property `petalCount` so its undefined.

In the function `bloom` we are binding the `this` of `LateBloomer` to the declare function by which we will have access to the `LateBloomer`'s object `petalCount`.

`this` in JavaScript is a very difficult to fathom at first.

MDN Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: But why this is not referring to global object.It is inside settimeout right?

Answer (score 0):

```
function LateBloomer() {
  this.name = 'triven'; //simplified property
}

// Some thoughts we discuss main requirement.
LateBloomer.prototype.bloom = function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {console.log(this);}, 1000); //Logs window: We all know that keyword this INSIDE CALLBACK 
                                                            //function refers to Window [Comment 1]
  //window.setTimeout(console.log(this), 1000); /Attentions: Here it is very easy to MISUNDERSTAND 
                                                //that keyword this is inside setTimeout and it should refer to window. 
                                                //Please note that here keyword this is not INSIDE CALLBACK function so here 
                                                //keyword this will refer to object on which its wrapper function is 
                                                //executed(in our case flower). [Comment 2]
};

//The requirement: We need to call .bloom and it should log name after 1 second. 
LateBloomer.prototype.bloom = function() {
    //here keyword this refers to object

   //window.setTimeout(function() {console.log(this);}, 1000); //But inside callback keyword this refers to window.

};

//We need some way to access object inside call back function so that its name can be accessed after 1 sec.

//step 1; Taking out anonymous function and adding it as a prototype property
LateBloomer.prototype.bloom = function() {
  //window.setTimeout(this.callback, 1000); //Note: Keyword this is not inside callback so 
                                            //it is referring to object (not window). We can access newly 
                                            //defined function on the object.  Also keyword this placed inside callback 
                                            //function(below) will still refer to window. 

};
LateBloomer.prototype.callback = function() {console.log(this.name);} 

//step 2; bringing .bind into picture.

    //Definition of .bind as per MDN : The bind() method creates a new function 
    //that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value

LateBloomer.prototype.bloom = function() {
  window.setTimeout(this.callback.bind(this), 1000); // Okay now we are now invoking .callback method on the object and 
                                                    //passing the same object to bind. 
                                                    // The keyword this inside newly return function (as a result of bind) will now refer to object
                                                    // we passed as argument to bind and we should not be able to access name property of our object.
                                                    // Note : Here both this keywords refers to same object ie on which which are calling .bloom.
                                                    //Note : we are no longer using passing callback function defined below. Instead we are now passing 
                                                    // and exact copy of it but configuring it in such a way that keyword this start refering to object we passed.

};
LateBloomer.prototype.callback = function() {console.log(this.name);}
```