# this keyword inside setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, this

This question is related to topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38736902/settimeout-bind-and-this)

I was expecting console to log window but it is logging LateBloomer. Please help me understand.

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @SurajRao : Ok I will take care in future.

Comment: What do you mean by: "expecting console to log window"?

Comment: You are writing a method on LateBloomer and hence using 'this' keyword you would be referring to that Object not the window object. Anyways what do you wanna log in window?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643714/settimeout-calls-function-immediately-instead-of-after-delay

Comment: In the mean time I get more down votes. Here is my understanding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38736902/settimeout-bind-and-this/48703271#48703271 . And I don't care about down votes :)

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
window.setTimeout(console.log(this), 1000);
```

calls `console.log(this)`, and passes its return value (`undefined`) into `setTimeout`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` calls `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`. So the `this` that gets logged is the current `this` where that line of code is.

Whereas in the linked question, they're doing this:

```
window.setTimeout(this.declare.bind(this), 1000);
```

which calls `bind` and passes its return value (a bound function) into `setTimeout`.

Comment: too lazy to look for the dupe? ;)

Comment: @epascarello: You know, I closed it as a dupe but of the wrong dupetarget, then...for some reason, didn't critically evaluate that it might be (well, must be) a dupe of a *different* dupetarget! Good point, thanks.

Comment: @epascarello: Specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643714/settimeout-calls-function-immediately-instead-of-after-delay if you'll do the honors?

Comment: @epascarello: I've never been that happy with it. Do you have a better target? I'd love to switch to a better one.

Comment: I guess I was not able to express my queries clearly so your answers didn't help much. I am developing my understanding  and documenting it. I am sure I will get my head around it soon. I would like to share my notes . I will post my observations here if you find them in right direction and you think they relate to this question. https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9vqthx9jigccgb/thiskeyword.PNG?dl=0